# jQuery text colour change animation

Tags: jquery, animation, text, colors

I've been rattling my head today to try and get a mouseover text colour changing script, that animates from changing the first letter of the string then each letter after that.

So effectively it creates almost a colour slide in change? I hope you understand what i mean.

I got really confused and ended up getting the text i wanted animated into a string, converting the string to an array then using a loop with set timeout to change each element in the array to the new color.

but my logic is all over the place im sure and things just are not working!!

could somebody please give this a look over or provide me with a solution! thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/qTbzq/

Comment: So, each letter is supposed to turn yellow with 3 seconds in between on mouseover?

Comment: the mouseover is supposed to trigger the colour change sequence yes, and the sequence is to turn each letter yellow with a short delay between, i set 3 secs as a test

Comment: Ok, so you are going for a kind of "cascade" of yellow letters across the screen, right?

Comment: yeah! I couldnt really think of the word to describe it while googling premade scripts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qTbzq/24/)**.

jQuery:

```
var string = $('h2').text();
var letters = string.split('');
var x = string.length;
$('h2').text('');
$.each(letters, function(index) {
    $('h2').append('<span id="e' + index + '" class="normal">' + letters[index] + '</span>');

});
function Animate(elem) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#e'+elem).animate({
            'color': 'yellow'
        }, 500, function(){elem++;Animate(elem)});
    }, 50);
}
$('h2').mouseenter(function() {
    Animate('0');
}).mouseleave(function() {});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>OWEN MELBOURNE</h2>
```

Comment: The only problem with that (and I'd hardly call it a problem) is that your code attempts to color toe space between the words (and obviously fails), resulting in a noticeable lapse between highlighting the N and the M between the two words.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - If it's a problem for the OP it can be easily changed.

Comment: thanks a lot also! this is another great help to me!! works beautifully! - yeah the time lapse is noticeable but i'll add a statement into the convert string to array that will drop the blank space :) thanks!

Comment: @OwenMelbourne- No problem. If you need me to post a modified jsFiddle just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Took me forever, but try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mQ2UV/3/

```
$(function() {
    var h2 = $('h2');
    var letters = h2.text().split('');
    var n = letters.length;

    h2.html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        h2.append("<span class='normal' id='l" + i + "'>" + letters[i] + "</span>");
    }

    var attached = false;

    $('h2').mouseover(function() {
        if (attached) {
            return;
        }
        attached = true;

        var n = 1;

        $("span").each(function() {
            var t = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(t).removeClass("normal").addClass("yellow");
            }, 100 * n);
            n++;
        });

    });
});​
```

Comment: ah thanks so much! Yeah I'd no idea how something that seems so simple would take so much effort! thanks a lot for your help it did work a treat!:D

Comment: Glad it helps! I was having trouble using `setTimeout` to make the delay. I guess that's what I get for not working with JavaScript for a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the color changing text script using Jquery Event change() method in the following link.. Free script is available.

http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/color-changing-text.php

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.